# Bind9 container can't resolve domain name

Tags: dns, docker, bind

I have set up a Bind9 container in order to allow my host machine to resolve "www.beesafe.co" as my apache server (which is running in another container with 172.19.0.4 IP address).

However, I cannot even resolve this address inside the Bind9 container itself using nslookup command. I think I have set my config files wrong.

Here are the four config files I copied inside the container (I followed a tutorial since I'm new to this).

named.conf.local :

```
zone "beesafe.co" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/forward.beesafe.co";
};

zone "0.19.172.in-addr-arpa" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/reverse.beesafe.co";
};
```

named.conf.options :

```
options {
 directory "/var/cache/bind";

 forwarders {
  8.8.8.8;
  9.9.9.9;
 };
 
 dnssec-validation auto;

 listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

forward.beesafe.co :

```
$TTL 20
@ IN SOA beesafe.co. root.beesafe.co. (
         2  ; Serial
         20 ; Refresh
         20 ; Retry
         20  ; Expire
         20 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN NS beesafe.co.
@ IN A 172.19.0.4
www IN A 172.19.0.4
#@ IN AAAA 1234:1234::1
```

reverse.beesafe.co :

```
$TTL 20
@ IN SOA beesafe.co. root.beesafe.co (
         1  ; Serial
        20  ; Refresh
        20  ; Retry
        20  ; Expire
        20 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN NS beesafe.co.
4 IN PTR beesafe.co.
```

And here is the command I use to launch my container :

```
sudo docker run --name bind9-dns-server --rm -it
-v /home/yael/Web_server/bind9-settings/forward.beesafe.co:/etc/bind/forward.beesafe.co
-v /home/yael/Web_server/bind9-settings/reverse.beesafe.co:/etc/bind/reverse.beesafe.co
-v /home/yael/Web_server/bind9-settings/named.conf.local:/etc/bind/named.conf.local
-v /home/yael/Web_server/bind9-settings/named.conf.options:/etc/bind/named.conf.options
ubuntu/bind9
```

I also tried to launch it with "--net host" attribute but it doesn't seem to help resolving this address on my host.

Could you help me find the problem here ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Have you checked any form of logs from Bind?

Comment: Here are the logs I get when lauching the bind container https://traff.co/I68ZJb2J

Comment: Right, it tells you the problem around lines 147-149.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I've been able to locate an "#" character in one of the config files. The logs seem clean now but I'm still unable to resolve this domain name inside nor outside the container